# data not get in select section more times

Tags: php

when i click update button without any change in editing form..the fields of product category and product brand become empty... and in database the record at that place also become empty.please help me what i should do for this problem.

```
<?php
include("include/db.php");
if(isset($_GET['edit_pro'])){
    $get_id=$_GET['edit_pro'];
    $get_pro="select * from products where product_id='$get_id'";
    $run_pro=mysqli_query($db, $get_pro);

    $row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro);
    $pro_id=$row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_title=$row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_image1=$row_pro['product_img1'];
    $pro_image2=$row_pro['product_img2'];
    $pro_image3=$row_pro['product_img3'];
    $pro_price=$row_pro['product_price'];
    $pro_desc=$row_pro['product_desc'];
    $pro_keywords=$row_pro['product_keywords'];
    $pro_cat=$row_pro['cat_id'];
    $pro_brand=$row_pro['brand_id'];

    $get_cat="select * from categories where cat_id='$pro_cat'";
    $run_cat=mysqli_query($db,$get_cat);
    $row_cat=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat);
    $cat_title=$row_cat['cat_title'];

    $get_brand="select * from brands where brand_id='$pro_brand'";
    $run_brand=mysqli_query($db,$get_brand);
    $row_brand=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brand);
    $brand_title=$row_brand['brand_title'];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head><title>update product</title>
<!--text editor taken from tinymce.com-->
<!--<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" align="center">
<center><table width="700" align="center">
<tr align="center" style="background-color:transparent;">
<td colspan="2"><h2>edit product</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr class="button_row">
<td align="right"><b>product title</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_title" value="<?php echo $pro_title; ?>" size="40" placeholder="enter title" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; border:1px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product category</b></td>
<td>
<select name="product_cat" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; border:1px solid black; opacity:0.6;">
<option value=""><?php echo $cat_title; ?></option>
<?php
    $get_cats="select * from categories";
    $run_cats=mysqli_query($db,$get_cats);
    while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id=$row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title=$row_cats['cat_title'];
    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product brand</b></td>
<td>
<select name="product_brand" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; border:1px solid black; opacity:0.6;">
<option value=""><?php echo $brand_title; ?></option>
<?php
    $get_brands="select * from brands";
    $run_brands=mysqli_query($db,$get_brands);
    while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        $brand_id=$row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title=$row_brands['brand_title'];
    echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product image 1</b></td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_img1" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; opacity:0.7;"><img src="product_images/<?php echo $pro_image1; ?>" width="60" height="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product image 2</b></td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_img2" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; opacity:0.7;"><img src="product_images/<?php echo $pro_image2; ?>" width="60" height="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product image 3</b></td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_img3" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; opacity:0.7;"><img src="product_images/<?php echo $pro_image3; ?>" width="60" height="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product price</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $pro_price; ?>" placeholder="enter price" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; border:1px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product description</b></td>
<td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="enter description" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; border:1px solid black; outline: none;"><?php echo $pro_desc; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>product keywords</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="40" value="<?php echo $pro_keywords; ?>" placeholder="enter keywords" style="background-color:transparent; color:gray; border:1px solid black;"></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="button_row">
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update" value="update product" style="background-color:transparent; width:120px; height:25px; font-size:15px; color:black; padding-bottom:10px; border:2px solid gray; text-align:center;"></td>
</tr>

</table></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $update_id=$pro_id;
    $product_title=$_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat=$_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand=$_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price=$_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc=$_POST['product_desc'];
    $status='on';
    $product_keywords=$_POST['product_keywords'];

    //image names
    $product_img1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['name'];
    $product_img2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['name'];
    $product_img3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['name'];

    //image temo names
    $temp_name1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];


    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"product_images/$product_img1");
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"product_images/$product_img2");
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name3,"product_images/$product_img3");

    if(!empty($_FILES['product_img1']['name']) AND 
       !empty($_FILES['product_img2']['name']) AND 
       !empty($_FILES['product_img3']['name']))
    {

        $update_product="update products set cat_id='$product_cat',
                                brand_id='$product_brand',
                                product_title='$product_title',
                                product_price='$product_price',
                                product_img1='$product_img1',
                                product_img2='$product_img2',
                                product_img3='$product_img3',
                                product_desc='$product_desc',
                                product_keywords='$product_keywords' 
                         where product_id='$update_id'";

    } else {
        $update_product="update products set cat_id='$product_cat',
                                brand_id='$product_brand',
                                product_title='$product_title',
                                product_price='$product_price',
                                product_desc='$product_desc',
                                product_keywords='$product_keywords' 
                         where product_id='$update_id'";

    }

    $run_update=mysqli_query($db, $update_product);
    if($run_update){
        echo "<script>alert('product has been updated')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_products','_self')   </script>";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Your ELSE is updating values even though youo dont check that those variables have any data in them

Comment: those fields shows the data that is present in database.firstly there is data in database but later on after clicking on update button without any change in form, the fields bocome empty and database also have not data about that fields

Comment: No everything that starts `$product_` comes from the form